# Can't show data from database by the client

Tags: mongodb, sveltekit

I'm storing user data and games data in a mongodb database, I use SvelteKit as a framework for my project, I'm currently working on a way to get the data from the database and show it to the user, the data is fetched from the server with no issues, that's my +page.server.ts code:

```
import { User_Model } from "$lib/server/models";

export async function load(event): Promise<any> {
  const email = event.cookies.get("email");

  const user = await User_Model.findOne({ "user.email": email });

  if (!user) {
    return { status: 400, error: new Error("User could not be found") };
  } else {
    const games = user.games.map((game) => {
      const gameCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(game));
      delete gameCopy._id; // Remove the _id field
      return gameCopy;
    });
    console.log({ games });
    return { games };
  }
}
```

, and that's the user model imported:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const User_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    email: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, require: true },
    name: { type: String, require: true },
  },
  games: [
    {
      id: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
      teams: {type: String},
      data: { type: String },
    },
  ],
});

export const User_Model = mongoose.model("User", User_Schema);
```

, the data is correctly logged in the server console, but the data, so the teams, the id and the data is not shown by the client, that is the client side code ( the +page.svelte):

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let games: any[];
  console.log(games)
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>Golf Games - Games</title>
</svelte:head>

{#if games && games.length > 0}
  <h1>Games:</h1>
  {#each games as game}
    <div>
      <h2>Game ID: {game.id}</h2>
      <p>Teams: {game.teams}</p>
      <p>Data: {game.data}</p>
    </div>
  {/each}
{:else}
  <p class="error">No games found.</p>
{/if}
```

I expected, that the game data is showed by the client, so the user can look at it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you are following some tutorial, I suspect you are following an outdated one.  Have a look at the official SvelteKit tutorial as well.*

The data returned from the `load` function is made available through the `data` prop in the corresponding page component:

```html
<script>
  export let data
</script>

{#each data.games as game}
```

There is also a built-in helper for error statuses:

```js
if (!user) throw error(404, "User not found")
```